# CiviMail - Sender appearing as "Info #NAME?"

Tags: civimail

When emails we send from Civi are viewed on phone devices, the sender in the preview appears as 'Info #NAME?'. On desktop, it works fine.

Can anyone identify the problem/suggest solution?

Thank you

Holly

Answer (score 1):

The first place to check is here:
/civicrm/admin/domain?action=update&reset=1

```
FROM Name
FROM Email Address
```